# Calculating width of scrollbar and using result in calc() css

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, width, scrollbar

I want to calculate the width of the scrollbar so that I use the result in a CSS `calc()` declaration.

At the moment, I assume that the width of the scrollbar is always `17px`, like this:

```css
body { 
    width:calc(100vw - 17px); 
}
.container { 
    max-width:calc(100vw - 17px); 
}
```

The problem with this is when you choose a different browser zoom %, the width of the scrollbar changes. So I want to use the result of the calculation to do something along these lines:

```css
body { 
    width:calc(100vw - CALCULATED SCROLL-BAR WIDTH); 
}
.container { 
    max-width:calc(100vw - CALCULATED SCROLL-BAR WIDTH); 
}
```

**EDIT:** I've now solved the problem with the help of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382516/getting-scroll-bar-width-using-javascript)

**The JavaScript used to calculate the scrollbar width (though, I have found you require an interval to get it to autoupdate):**

```js
function getScrollbarWidth() {
  var outer = document.createElement("div");
  outer.style.visibility = "hidden";
  outer.style.width = "100px";
  outer.style.msOverflowStyle = "scrollbar"; // needed for WinJS apps

  document.body.appendChild(outer);

  var widthNoScroll = outer.offsetWidth;
  // force scrollbars
  outer.style.overflow = "scroll";

  // add innerdiv
  var inner = document.createElement("div");
  inner.style.width = "100%";
  outer.appendChild(inner);        

  var widthWithScroll = inner.offsetWidth;

  // remove divs
  outer.parentNode.removeChild(outer);

  return widthNoScroll - widthWithScroll;
}
```

**My code (which is used to embed the result of the function into a CSS `calc()` declaration).**

```js
$('body').css({ 
  'width':'calc(100vw - ' + getScrollbarWidth() + 'px)' 
});

$('.container').css({ 
  'max-width':'calc(100vw - ' + getScrollbarWidth() + 'px)' 
});
```

Comment: So how would I make this work for my example?

Comment: Do you use it for one specific browser or you want it for all kinds? I am afraid that you will have to use some JavaScript.

Comment: For all kinds, but I have solved the problem now. I'll update the question with my solution.

Answer (score 22):

Actually, you can get the scrollbar width just with css and custom properties (and completely without javascript):

```
body {
    --scrollbar-width: calc(100vw - 100%);
}
```

Then you can use this variable in a child element like this:

```
.container { 
    max-width: calc(100vw - var(--scrollbar-width)); 
}
```

This is because 100vw is always the inner width of the view, but the 100% of the body does not include the scrollbar.

Comment: Should be noted that this only works if your body element has a scroll bar.

Comment: Also note that this will not work if `.container` is not the same width as `body` since the "100%" is relative to where the `--scrollbar-width` variable is used.

Comment: The variable can be useful but it's not required, as the value can be calculated with `calc(100vw - (100vw - 100%))` as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34884924/21849374) a few years earlier

Answer (score 10):

Expanding jonas_jonas's answer, it can work but if `.container` must have the same width as the body.

If that's not the case, even so you can make it work with vanilla JS, defining a CSS property like this

```
document.body.style.setProperty(
    "--scrollbar-width",
    `${window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth}px`
);
```

And then you can use it in CSS

```
.container { 
    max-width: calc(100vw - var(--scrollbar-width)); 
}
```

Comment: The one issue with this solution is that on macOS the scrollbar width will change when the user switches between mouse and trackpad (it happens for me when I unplug my mouse), so you can't just calculate the value once

Answer (score 2):

Why you need so much code to do that?

The easy way with plain javascript it's:

```
$('body').css({ 
  'width':'calc(100vw - ' + (window.innerWidth - document.body.clientWidth) + 'px)' 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be organized with the use of the new container queries with pure CSS on any scrolling area:

```html
    <div style="container-type: inline-size;">
        <div style="overflow-y: auto; height=300px;">
            <div style="padding-right: calc(40px - 100cqw + 100%)">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I thought this was a really cool idea, but it seems to not work in Safari (100cqw == 100% in Safari). This may be https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52653