# Align div-based table's body having vertical scrollbar with the table's title

Tags: html, css

Consider:

```css
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

.TitleRow {
  width: 200px;
}

.Body {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.Cell {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="TitleRow">
  <div class="Cell">
      Column 1
  </div>
  <div class="Cell">
      Column 2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="Body">
  <div class="BodyRow">
    <div class="Cell">
      Data 1
    </div>
    <div class="Cell">
      Data 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the widths of the cells need to be specified in percentages and the table body needs a vertical bar.

The problem is that the vertical scrollbar in the table body takes up space and prevents the cells of the table's body to be aligned with the column titles. How can I fix this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/39392423/1264804. Set matching padding on your heading row.

Comment: @isherwood If you mean [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75817480/2725810), I still can't see how to do this for my example without JS to compute the difference between the `offsetWidth` and `clientWidth` of the body and then apply that as the right padding for the header...

Comment: without js, a trivial answer would be: add the width of scroll to `body`, something like `width: 215px`, it works but is not much beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper table tags, it's more readable and easy to style:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

```
tr {
  text-align: center;
}
```