# Translating html element using view width leave uneven spacing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why does `translateX` using `vw` leave uneven spacing when there is a scrollbar?

When I translate the `ul` elements away from each other upon scrolling, the leftover space between the start of the viewport and the first `ul` is smaller than the space between the end of the viewport and the last `ul`. This only happen when there is a scrollbar in the page.
Here are the snippets:

```
<nav class='navbar flex-container'>
  <ul class='nav-item__container flex-container'>
        ...
  </ul>
  <ul class='nav-item__container flex-container'>
        ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-container.scrolled nav .nav-item__container:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateX(calc(-50vw + 100%));
}

.nav-container.scrolled nav .nav-item__container:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateX(calc(50vw - 100%));
}
```

I fixed this by getting the width of the scrollbr and adding it to the original `translateX` of the first `ul` element.

```
let scrollbarWidth = window.innerWidth - body.offsetWidth;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    // nav menu item animatate on scroll
    if (window.scrollY >= 10) {
        navContainer.classList.add('scrolled');
        navItemContainer.style.transform = `translateX(calc(-45vw + 100% + ${scrollbarWidth}px))`;
    } else {
        navContainer.classList.remove('scrolled');
        navItemContainer.removeAttribute('style');
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to calculate the Viewport Width (vw) without scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606565/is-it-possible-to-calculate-the-viewport-width-vw-without-scrollbar)

Comment: "vw" calculates the width of screen including scrollbar.