# When using "height: 100vh" for the container, vertical scrollbar appears

Tags: css

I want the content to take the full height of the browser window, but not beyond.

When using 100vh as the container height, I can see the vertical scrollbar appearing.

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 3px solid lightsteelblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

What could be the issue?

**EDIT:**
more detailed code:

**CSS**

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.page_content {
  height: 85vh;
  width: 95vw;
  border: 3px solid lightsteelblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.footer {
  height: 14vh;
  width: 95vw;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
   <body>
     <div class="container">
        <div class="page_content">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
         ...
        </div>
     </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just for your information. 100vh can, and will, behave weird on mobile browsers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser

Comment: @DanielZiegler thanks, it's not made for mobile browsers

Comment: For anyone experiencing this problem in Firefox, it could actually be *heading margin* causing it! See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68367701/2454914) for details.

Comment: For me this was caused by the presence of an `inline-block` element and was resolved by adding `vertical-align: top` to it's style, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592052/5560171).

Answer (score 95):

By default `body` and `html` are assigned to `margin` or `padding` to some pixels. Try using following code.

1vh = 1% of veiwport height
100vh = 100% of height.

So never calculate height - 3px. like this

```
body,html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: In my case it did not helped me. Changing back to the default font in the footer did fix it though... So I added `height: 1.5rem` to the footer and it did the fix. I guess there is some edge on how vh/flex-grow compute the height with some fonts

Answer (score 29):

The issue is that you have a border with it, and like padding, you have to add it to your height.

Either you use this :

```
.container {
    height: calc(100vh - 3px);
}
```

Or this :

```
.container {
    height: 100vh;
    border: 3px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: which part isn't ?

Comment: @VijayKumarB He definitely is correct. Also keep in mind, that the body can have a margin.

Comment: Ok so you tell me I'm not correct because you think otherwise ? That's not really being open minded. And your answer is the same as mine for all I see. Thank you @DanielZiegler, didn't think about that !

Comment: No, 100vh means that your component height is 100% of the view. But it doesn't fit. Try adding some margin and padding, and tell me if it still fits.

Comment: @VijayKumarB Yea. 100vh fits in the viewport. but 100vh + 3px border are  higher than the the whole viewport. Dont know what to say else as your answers shows me you know something about the box model. But you should go and read it again

Comment: `box-sizing` **doesn't fit**, it just **tells the browser to take the padding and border into consideration when calculating the height**

Comment: @VijayKumarB So... See? This answer is absolutely correct. Im out :'D

Comment: Why not use equivalent `vh` like instead of `px` ? eg. `97vh` ?

Answer (score 9):

There is a user agent stylesheet that gets added to any web document, it's nothing but default set of style that each browser applies to the documents being viewed, however these rules have the a very lower precedence order. 
Of course the author can over ride these rules, and they do very often.

As of today, google chrome, adds 8px margin to your document if not added or over written by the author.

So let's consider you added a div in your entire HTML document called .container in your case.
You may try doing something like this.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    //if you want to add border to this container,
    border: 1px solid cyan;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Further if you have any other divs inside the container, they would take advantage of .container class 100vh value. You can assign 70% height to .page-content and 30% height to .footer div.

```
.page-content {
     height: 70%
     border: 1px solid aquablue;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
.footer {
     height: 30%;
}
```

Comment: when i tried it giving margin and height for body it removed the scroll, thanks. But when i have given the height as 100% the div border if content is empty then the border line wont come till down

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

and

```css
.container {
     height: 100vh;
     border: 3px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 3px solid lightsteelblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

This did the trick. See and test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/jsenLgre/

Answer (score 0):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you write this at the beginning of your codes, your problem will be fixed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Also, setting margin and padding for every element would not be recommended.

Answer (score -1):

Came across same scenario, some auto margins in browser causesthe vertical scroll bar to appear. Very simple workaround I came across is to use 99vh instead of 100vh

```
.container {
height: 99vh;
border: 3px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

Comment: This creates unsightly effects if your element and the body have two different background colors or images.

Comment: @jidu0106, I don't know what it is but this worked like a charm.

Comment: @DevYego It's just taking 99% viewport height instead of 100%. I used the "overflow-y:hidden;" solution to chop off the extra 4 pixels which aren't essential to my application.

Answer (score -3):

u can remove the scroll bar by overflow-y:hidden; and u should use calc function to remove ur header height example  height: 100vh;

calc(100vh -20px) if ur header is 20px height. so u get the 100vh !