# Why does 100vh produce horizontal and vertical scroll bar?

Tags: html, css

Hello I am a beginner learning Html & CSS.
I was creating this website from my method and I ran into trouble.
I tried searching many solutions on stack overflow none of them seems to work,
or I don't understand how they work.

I have tried solutions from [When using "height: 100vh" for the container, vertical scrollbar appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645465/when-using-height-100vh-for-the-container-vertical-scrollbar-appears)
but none of them seems to work.

So please if you mark this questions as duplicate, please comment and make me understand how to fix this error and then close it.

So when I assign 100vh to the bg-video class:

```
/* for laptop */
    @media (min-width:1024px) {
        .bg-video{
            /* 100vh introduces scroll bar on both sides */
            height: 100vh;
            /* height 99vh fixes it but leaves a black empty line below */
            /* height: 99vh;  */
        }
```

When the height is set to 100vh:
[image: height:100vh]

When the height is set to 99vh:
[image: height:99vh]

Full Html & CSS code (I know the code is long please refer to /* for laptop */ section in CSS ):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
    initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- font awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <!-- font awesome -->
    <style>
        *{
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        }
        /* page */
        body{
            background-color: black;
        }
        /* page */

        /* background section */
        .background{
          position: absolute;
        }
        .bg-video{
            width: 100vw;
            height: 320px;
            object-fit: cover;
            z-index: -1;
        }
        .overlay{
            background-color: black;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 320px;
            position:absolute;
            opacity: 0.5;
        }
        /* background section */
        /* header section */
        .con-head{
            position: relative;
            max-width: 1200px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        header{
            padding: 20px 20px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .logo{
            width: 130px;
        }
        .part1 a{
            display: none;
        }
        .login{
                display: none;
            }
        .part2 button{
                display: none;
            }
        .menu{
            width: 20px;
        }
        /* header section */
        /* turbo section */
        .turbo{
            position: relative;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            color: white;   
            max-width: 1200px;
        }
        .turbo h1{
            font-size: 2rem;
            color: white;
            line-height: 1em;
        }
        .turbo span{
            color: rgb(20, 212, 212);
        }
        .turbo p{
            padding: 10px 0;
            font-size: 0.9rem;
        }
        .turbo button{
            color: rgb(21, 4, 82);
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: bold;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            background-color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border: none;
            position: relative;
            top: 20px;
            /* gives width of 100 viewport*/
            width: 100vw;
            /* this makes width relative to its parent  */
            max-width: 100%;
        }
        .turbo button:hover{
            background-color: rgb(20, 212, 212);
            color: rgb(21, 4, 82);
        }
        
        /* turbo section */

        /* for small screens */
        @media (max-width:380px) {
            .logo{
                width: 30vw;
            }
            .part1 a{
              display: none;
            }
            .part2 :nth-child(2){
                display: none;
            }
            .part2 button{
                display: none;
            }
            .menu{
                width: 5vw;
            }
            .turbo h1{
                font-size: 8vw;
            }
            .turbo p{
                font-size: 4vw;
            }
            .turbo button{
                font-size: 4vw;
            }
            .bg-video{
                height: 54vh;
            }
            .overlay{
                height: 54vh;
            }
        }
        /* for small screens */
        /* for laptop */
        @media (min-width:1024px) {
            .bg-video{
                /* 100vh introduces Scroll bar on both sides */
                /* height: 100vh; */
                /* height 99vh fixes it but leaves a black empty line below */
                height: 99vh; 
            }
            .overlay{
                height: 130px;
                background: rgb(0,0,0);
                background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0,0,0,1) 43%, rgba(0,0,0,0.5606617647058824) 71%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 85%);
                opacity: 0.6;
            }
            .logo{
                width: 150px;
            }
            .menu{
                display: none;
            }
            /* dont know why but this fixed the padding issue */
            .con-head{
                padding: 20px 20px;
            }
            header{
                padding: 20px 0px;
            }
            .part1{
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .part1 a{
                /* making them visible */
                display: block;
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
                padding: 0 20px;
                font-weight:500;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
            }
            .part1 a:hover{
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .part1 :nth-child(2){
                margin-left: 20px;
            }
            .part2{
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .login{
                display: block;
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: 500;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                padding:0 20px;
            }
            .login:hover{
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
            .part2 button{
                display: block;
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                padding:10px 20px;
                background-color: rgb(20, 212, 212);
                border: none;
                border-radius: 999px;
            }
            .part2 button:hover{
                color: rgb(21, 4, 82);
                background-color: white;
            }
            .turbo{
                position: relative;
                top: 50px;
            }
            .turbo h1{
                font-size: 3rem;
            }
            .turbo p{
                font-size: 1em;
                margin-top: 15px;
            }
            .turbo button{
                width: 200px;
                border-radius: 999px;
                margin-top: 20px;
            }    
        }
     
        /* for laptop */
    </style>
    <title>Chris Courses</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <!-- background video -->
        <section class="background">
            <div class="overlay"></div>   
                <video src="https://chriscourses.com/_nuxt/videos/galaxy.b6c8fb5.mp4"
                autoplay
                muted
                loop
                class="bg-video"
                >
                </video>
        </section>
        <!-- head -->
        <section class="con-head">
            <header>
                <!-- p1 -->
                <div class="part1">
                <img src="logo.svg" alt="" class="logo">
                <!-- laptop screen -->
                <a href="">Courses</a>
                <a href="">Forum</a>
                <a href="">Pricing</a>
                <!-- laptop screen -->
                </div>
                <!-- p2 -->
                <div class="part2">
                <a href="">
                <img src="menu.svg" alt="" class="menu">
                </a>
                <a href="" class="login">LOGIN</a>
                <button>SIGN UP</button>
                </div>
            </header>
        </section>
        <!-- turbo charge section -->
        <div class="turbo">
                <h1>Turbocharge your<br>
                    <span>development career</span>
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Chris Courses provides students and professionals <br>
                    a college-level web development education.
                </p>
                <button>Get&nbsp;started</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's because of the video, it does not have the same ratio

Comment: can we fix it by CSS? Please explain more thanks!

Comment: @Lk77 but the video is styled as object-fit cover so does its ratio matter?

Comment: That's exactly what I am thinking aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add `display: block;` to the `.bg-video` and it fixes the issue

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}


/* page */

body {
  background-color: black;
}


/* page */


/* background section */

.background {
  position: absolute;
}

.bg-video {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 320px;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.overlay {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* background section */


/* header section */

.con-head {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

header {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 130px;
}

.part1 a {
  display: none;
}

.login {
  display: none;
}

.part2 button {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  width: 20px;
}


/* header section */


/* turbo section */

.turbo {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  color: white;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.turbo h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: white;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.turbo span {
  color: rgb(20, 212, 212);
}

.turbo p {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.turbo button {
  color: rgb(21, 4, 82);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  /* gives width of 100 viewport*/
  width: 100vw;
  /* this makes width relative to its parent  */
  max-width: 100%;
}

.turbo button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(20, 212, 212);
  color: rgb(21, 4, 82);
}


/* turbo section */


/* for small screens */

@media (max-width:380px) {
  .logo {
    width: 30vw;
  }
  .part1 a {
    display: none;
  }
  .part2 :nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
  .part2 button {
    display: none;
  }
  .menu {
    width: 5vw;
  }
  .turbo h1 {
    font-size: 8vw;
  }
  .turbo p {
    font-size: 4vw;
  }
  .turbo button {
    font-size: 4vw;
  }
  .bg-video {
    height: 54vh;
  }
  .overlay {
    height: 54vh;
  }
}


/* for small screens */


/* for laptop */

@media (min-width:1024px) {
  .bg-video {
    height: 100vh;
  }
  .overlay {
    height: 130px;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 43%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5606617647058824) 71%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 85%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 150px;
  }
  .menu {
    display: none;
  }
  /* dont know why but this fixed the padding issue */
  .con-head {
    padding: 20px 20px;
  }
  header {
    padding: 20px 0px;
  }
  .part1 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .part1 a {
    /* making them visible */
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  }
  .part1 a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .part1 :nth-child(2) {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .part2 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .login {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .login:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .part2 button {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: rgb(20, 212, 212);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 999px;
  }
  .part2 button:hover {
    color: rgb(21, 4, 82);
    background-color: white;
  }
  .turbo {
    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
  }
  .turbo h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  .turbo p {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .turbo button {
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
}


/* for laptop */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<div class="page">
  <!-- background video -->
  <section class="background">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <video src="https://chriscourses.com/_nuxt/videos/galaxy.b6c8fb5.mp4" autoplay muted loop class="bg-video">
                </video>
  </section>
  <!-- head -->
  <section class="con-head">
    <header>
      <!-- p1 -->
      <div class="part1">
        <img src="logo.svg" alt="" class="logo">
        <!-- laptop screen -->
        <a href="">Courses</a>
        <a href="">Forum</a>
        <a href="">Pricing</a>
        <!-- laptop screen -->
      </div>
      <!-- p2 -->
      <div class="part2">
        <a href="">
          <img src="menu.svg" alt="" class="menu">
        </a>
        <a href="" class="login">LOGIN</a>
        <button>SIGN UP</button>
      </div>
    </header>
  </section>
  <!-- turbo charge section -->
  <div class="turbo">
    <h1>Turbocharge your<br>
      <span>development career</span>
    </h1>
    <p>
      Chris Courses provides students and professionals <br> a college-level web development education.
    </p>
    <button>Get&nbsp;started</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, can you explain why it worked and what was happening?

Comment: Inline display items always have this weird spacing below them. Same thing would happen with span or img — not sure if it’s a bug or expected behaviour or what, just something I’ve been dealing with for like 10 years