# Scrolling and overflow in react: why is the whole app scrollable instead of just the div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I recreated a very simple react project to showcase the issue I am facing.

In this project, I have a simple header, a sidebar and a main-page. In the main-page element, I have a button to add a new document to a list of document. The list is displayed vertically just bellow the button. The app container element height is set to 100vh. The behavior I want to achieve is having just the main-page element scrollable when the document list becomes too long. Here is the complete typescript code of the project:

DebugApp.tsx:

```
import "./debugapp.css"

import React, { useState } from 'react';

interface Document {
    title: string;
    doc_id: number
}

function DebugApp() {
    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState<Document[]>([]);

    const addElement = () => {
        setDocuments( [...documents, {title: 'test', doc_id: 1}])
    }

    return (
        <div className="app-container">
          <div className="header">Header</div>
          <div className="main">
            <div className="sidebar"/>
            <div className="main-page">
                <button onClick={addElement}> add </button>
              <ul className="document-list-container">
                  {documents.map((document: Document) => {return<li className='doc'>{document.title}</li>})}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DebugApp;
```

And here is the associated css code (with flashy colors for debug purposes, header in green, sidebar in red, and main-page in blue):

debugapp.css:

```
.app-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.main-page {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #0000ff;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.doc {
  height: 4rem;
  color: white;
}
```

What happens here is not making any sens for the moment. In the beginning, the website looked like what I wanted:

[image: Image: First app look]

When I add some documents, it behaves as expected:

[image: Image: Everything is normal]

But just as I reach the browser screen size limit, this happens:

[image: Image: Whole app is scrollable]

The header shrinks and the entire app becomes scrollable by just the height of the header.

If I keep adding docs, the main-page becomes now scrollable and the second scrollbar appears:

[image: Image: Two scrollbar, unwanted behavior]

I made this debug app to have a minimal version that recreates the problem.

I don't understand why the appcontainer height becomes heigher that 100vh and why the header shrinks. All I want is that if there is not enough space on the main page, then just the main page becomes scrollable.

Any help would be greatly welcome, as this kind of behaviour is turning me crazy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When using "height: 100vh" for the container, vertical scrollbar appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44645465/when-using-height-100vh-for-the-container-vertical-scrollbar-appears)

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things going on here, and following these steps should hopefully get you desired results:

1. **Use [`min-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) instead of `height` for your `header` class.** The `height` property is basically just a suggestion, and using `min-height` means it won't collapse on itself past the size you specify.

*Example:*

```
.header {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

2. The height of your `main` element is set to `100%` of its parent despite sharing space inside `app-container` with `header`. This ultimately makes everything `100vh + 50px`: too large for the browser to handle without adding a scroll. **You can fix this by setting `main` to a height less than `100%`.**

*Example:*

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 90%;
}
```

3. **Lastly, we need to apply a [`max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height) to the `app-container` so it doesn't grow beyond its designated size.** We can remove the `flex` styles while we're at it.

*Example:*

```
.app-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

And that should be it! Making the above three CSS changes (and, in my case, setting the `margin` of `body` to 0) got me the following result after adding a bunch of list items:

[image: output]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly
I didn't know that height is just a suggestion.
Now I have just set the main height to `height: calc(100% - [HEADER HEIGHT]);` and it works perfectly